# Error connecting to Redis Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379

Tags: express, redis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elasticache

I am programming in **Express.js**, running within an **AWS Elastic Beanstalk** instance, trying to connect to an **AWS ElastiCache** instance with **Redis**.  I get this error:

```
web: Error connecting to Redis Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
web: at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) {
web: errno: -111,
web: code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
web: syscall: 'connect',
web: address: '127.0.0.1',
web: port: 6379
web: }
```

What is interesting is that I can **PING** Redis within the same program (and I get back a **PONG**), but I cannot connect using "createClient".

Here is the relevant code:

```
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
import express from "express";
import { createClient } from "redis";
import net from "net";

const app = express();

console.log("NOTE: Pre createClient");
console.log("*** HOST = ", process.env.REDIS_HOST);
console.log("*** PORT = ", process.env.REDIS_PORT);

//----------------------------------------
// Pinging Redis Server
//----------------------------------------

const client = new net.Socket();
client.setTimeout(5000);
client.connect(process.env.REDIS_PORT, process.env.REDIS_HOST, () => {
    client.write("PING\r\n");
});
client.on("data", (data) => {
    console.log("PING TEST: Reply: ", data.toString());
    client.destroy();
});
client.on("error", (err) => {
    console.error("PING TEST: Error connecting to Redis server:", err);
    client.destroy();
});
client.on("timeout", () => {
    console.error("PING TEST: Connection timed out.");
    client.destroy();
});

//----------------------------------------
// Connecting to Redis
//----------------------------------------

let redisClient = createClient({
    host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
    port: process.env.REDIS_PORT || 6379,
});
redisClient.on("connect", () => {
    console.log("Connected to Redis");
});
redisClient.on("error", (error) => {
    console.error("Error connecting to Redis", error);
});

console.log("NOTE: Pre connect");
console.log("*** redisClient = ", JSON.stringify(redisClient));

try {
    await redisClient.connect();
} catch (error) {
    console.error("Error connecting to Redis CLIENT:", err);
}
console.log("NOTE: Post connect");
```

Above the error listed above, I get this output

```
web:> *<name-of-app>*@1.0.0 start
web: > node index.js
web: NOTE: Pre createClient
web: *** HOST =  aia-elasti-redis.*<6 digits>*.clustercfg.euw1.cache.amazonaws.com
web: *** PORT =  6379
web: NOTE: Pre connect
web: *** redisClient =  {"_events":{},"_eventsCount":2,"bf":{},"cms":{},"cf":{},"tDigest":{},"topK":{},"graph":{},"json":{},"ft":{},"ts":{}}
web: PING TEST: Reply:  +PONG
```

Because I get back the "**PONG**", I know that:
(a) the Redis Server is running, and
(b) I can reach it from the Elastic Beanstalk server using the AWS Configuration Endpoint.

There is no username or password set up.  So, I cannot think of any other way to format the **createClient**

I find it odd that I do not see the "NOTE: Post connect" even though the redisClient.connect() is within a try/ catch.

Comment: Are you *sure* you're [passing in the arguments correctly](https://docs.redis.com/latest/rs/references/client_references/client_nodejs/)?

Comment: That worked!  Thanks.  I implemented the TLS format instead of the ACL format.

Answer (score 4):

Two solutions:

```
const client = redis.createClient({
    socket: {
        host: '<hostname>',
        port: '<port>'
    }
});
```

And:

```
createClient({
    url: 'redis://alice:foobared@awesome.redis.server:6380'
});
```

See:  https://redis.io/docs/clients/nodejs/

Comment: Thanks! My issue was that it was, for some reason, defaulting to trying to connect to the `::1` host instead of `127.0.01`. Technically the same thing but the my config was set to only allow connections from the IP address. This helped, thanks!